# Publishing an R package without defining the function argument

Tags: r

I'm currently in the process of making a package for someone out of their code. While running cmdcheck on R to upload the package to CRAN I keeping running into the issue: Argument "ftab" is missing, with no default. Is there a way for the check to ignore this?

I have tried a few things such as setting ftab = NULL, I have set ftab = ftab<-rbind(c(20,10,20),c(15,15,20)), and ftab = NA.

```
chi.stat<-function(ftab)
{

  tot<-sum(ftab);
  expv<-outer(rowSums(ftab)/tot,  colSums(ftab)/tot, '*')*tot;
  signal<-(colMeans(expv)<eps)*(1:dim(ftab)[2]);
  indx<-setdiff(signal,0);
  ftemp<-((ftab-expv)^2/expv)
  chi.val<-ifelse(length(indx)==0, sum(ftemp), sum(ftemp[,-indx]));

  return(chi.val);
}
```

EDIT:
Could the issue be located somewhere in here?

```
#' chi.stat function
#'
#' This function... (description here)
#' @param ftab (argument here)
#' @return chi.val (return value)
#' @export
#' @examples
#' chi.stat()
```

I have tried to input default arguments in the example as well which sort of fixes the no default issue but creates some different issues. Additionally, I feel as though it shouldn't require a default argument but I am unsure. If needed I can post my other function that calls chi.stat().

Comment: It doesn't look like the error would be in this particular chunk of code. Is there some other place in the package code where `chi.stat()` is called?

Comment: When I tested that code chunk, I got *"no visible binding for global variable 'eps'"*, but nothing for chi.stat.

Comment: @Marius I do have a second function that calls chi.stat a few times. But the code is at least twice as long as the code I already posted. The error always pops up when it gets to the "checking examples" portion of the cmd check. I added an edit to my post to show some additional info on the function.

Comment: @r2evans That's interesting, I will try to run through the function again separately and see what results I get. I'm starting to think the issue might be stemming from my `@examples chi.stat()`

Comment: Yes, your examples should normally be code that will run.  `chi.stat()` with no argument won't run.

Comment: @user2554330 Thank you, I added in a default and it did seem to fix that issue. When you put a default argument in that example ```chi.stat()``` does it only affect that example for the sake of the cmd check? I just want to make sure because I'm trying not to alter the main bit of code I'm working with.

Comment: ZyrtecTheWise: yes, it appears to be your use of `@examples`. The cmdcheck will run all code within the `@examples` section of code that is not explicitly within `\dontrun{ ... }` bookends. So your "example" is directly violating your own definition of the function, `function(ftab)`, that suggests it requires an argument. (I'll argue that an example of `chi.stat()` by itself is useless in that it doesn't show interaction with other functions/data and/or output expectations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to your `@examples` section. Change the definition to something like:

```r
#' chi.stat function
#'
#' This function... (description here)
#' @param ftab (argument here)
#' @param eps numeric, a tolerance factor; default 1e-9
#' @return chi.val (return value)
#' @export
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' chi.stat()
#' }
chi.stat<-function(ftab, eps = 1e-9)
{

  tot<-sum(ftab);
  expv<-outer(rowSums(ftab)/tot,  colSums(ftab)/tot, '*')*tot;
  signal<-(colMeans(expv)<eps)*(1:dim(ftab)[2]);
  indx<-setdiff(signal,0);
  ftemp<-((ftab-expv)^2/expv)
  chi.val<-ifelse(length(indx)==0, sum(ftemp), sum(ftemp[,-indx]));

  return(chi.val);
}
```

to keep cmdcheck from attempting to run all code within the examples section. (I added a default `eps` in the function arguments to fix another issue. You can define as an in-function constant if you'd like.)

**Better yet**, build a proper `ftab` argument manually in the `@examples` section (and do not use `\dontuse`). It's a type of CI testing in that each time you cmdcheck and/or build the package, it will run all of that code and complain about errors.

```r
#' chi.stat function
#'
#' This function... (description here)
#' @param ftab (argument here)
#' @param eps numeric, a tolerance factor; default 1e-9
#' @return chi.val (return value)
#' @export
#' @examples
#' m <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
#' chi.stat(m)
#' # [1] 0.07936508
```

Whether you include output in your `@examples` section is a matter of personal preference. If you want further CI-testing, then do something like

```r
#' @examples
#' m <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
#' ret <- chi.stat(m)
#' stopifnot(abs(ret - 0.07936508) < 1e-9)
```

It may not replace full testing, but if you don't have a formal unit-testing (perhaps via `testthat` in the package's `./tests/testthat/` folder), then this is better than nothing.

NB: make sure the 0.079 number is actually correct based on your function requirements. That is, if you are implementing some known process/algorithm, take a previously known or hand-calculated/verified input and output.

Comment: Examples are documentation for the user. You should not misuse them for tests.

Comment: @Roland, though I see what you mean (and agree on an academic level), I see so many "amateur" packages/functions that have mediocre or no code coverage. While proper testing is a Best Practice, certainly, I get to deal with a lot of really smart people who do not sufficiently understand/appreciate (or care about) the CS principles to actually code tests. But I bet they'd put in one or two things in documentation. So while the purist in me agrees with you, the pragmatist in me says *"I'll take what I can get"* (and then write formal tests myself).